# Method save does not exist occur after lockForUpdate Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### Laravel Cannot Save data to DB after Pessimistic Locking

I am facing the problem that cannot update data to db while using save method with Laravel 5.1.

I am trying to update data with locking to avoid concurrency data and below is my code.

Please help me.

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Recharge extends Model
{
public function processSuccess($orderId, $type, $amount) {
        $query = [
            ['status', '<=', 1],
            ['order_abm', '=', $orderId],
            ['type', '=', $type],
            ['amount', '=', $amount],
        ];

        \DB::beginTransaction();
        $concur_up = Recharge::where($query)->lockForUpdate()->get();
        $concur_up->status = 5;
        $concur_up->amounted = $amount;
        $concur_up->date    = time();
        $res =$concur_up->save();
        if (!$res) {
            return "fail";
        }
        \DB::commit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

error shown in my editor

[image]

error shown in my browser

[image]

My using table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my codes according to the answer above of Mr.Patricus and 
its work just after changing `->get()` to `->first()` . 
Here is my codes. Thanks for everyone's advise.

```
  class Recharge extends Model
    {
       public function processSuccess($orderId, $type, $amount) {
            $query = [
                ['status', '<=', 1],
                ['order_abm', '=', $orderId],
                ['type', '=', $type],
                ['amount', '=', $amount],
            ];

            \DB::beginTransaction();
            $concur_up = Recharge::where($query)->lockForUpdate()->first();
            $concur_up->status = 5;
            $concur_up->amounted = $amount;
            $concur_up->date    = time();
            $res =$concur_up->save();
            if (!$res) {
                return "fail";
            }
            \DB::commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `->get()` method will always return a `Collection`, even if there is only one record in that `Collection`.

If you know your where clause is designed to only return one record, or you only care about the first record it returns, then just change `->get()` to `->first()`, that will set `$concur_up` to a `Recharge` model instance instead of a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending model but not using the model in the code. Try adding `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` in the header. So your code will be something like this:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Recharge extends Model
{
    // Your code....
}
```

I guess this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Sir, I added it "use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;" and still cannot use save method. Please.